# Report Server Configuration Manager Encryption Keys Backuo button greyed out on one server but not another

Tags: reporting-services

Today I have configure SSR on two, supposedly identical Windows Server 2019 machines.

The first seem to go fine.

The second is proving more problematic.

Comparing Report Server Configuration Manager on each, whilst obviously server name, service account and passwords will be different, everything else is the same except the Backup button on the Encryption Keys page is greyed out on the problematic installation.

Any idea why that might be?

Thanks